# Change placeholder font style on native-base

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I use native base [Input Component](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Form), and I tried to customize the placeholder font style like the following example, but it does not change the placeholder. It changed the style of the user typed input value. How can I change the placeholder font style?

```
<Input
  style={{color:"blue", fontFamily:"Arial"}}
  placeholder="I am blue and Arial font"
/>
```

**Update**

I already tried `placeholderStyle` like the following example, but it does not work.

```
<Input
  placeholderStyle={{color:"blue", fontFamily:"Arial"}}
  placeholder="I am blue and Arial font"
/>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The font family is the same for the text input and the placeholder, however I assume you meant that the color didn't change for the placeholder, here's the solution.

Do this:

```
<Input
  style={{color:"blue", fontFamily:"Arial"}}
  placeholderTextColor="blue"
  placeholder="I am blue and Arial font"
/>
```

Comment: Ah, I think `fontFamily` does not affect with style. But, like you said, it does. Thanks!

Comment: No problems, glad I could help.

Comment: placeholderTextColor also can get "hex" colors.