# React-Native - TextInput - Make default value look like an entered value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm succesfully passing a default value to a TextInput in React-Native.  I can display this as a placeholder, but it is greyed out.  I want to display this value with the styling you would see if the user had entered it - not as a greyed out placeholder.

Is there any way to do this?

I looked at this: [Change placeholder font style on native-base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526396/change-placeholder-font-style-on-native-base)

It seems that you can change the TextColor of the placeholder, and all other styling is inherited from the TextInput, however it will greyed out if it's the placeholder.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add css on it (or wrap it into css) and design it like an active field? e.g.

```
a:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```